# Как получить путь для копирования файла из openfiledialog?

Tags: c++-cli

Привет, есть нерабочий код:

```
Path::GetDirectoryName(openFileDialog1->FileName);          
CopyFile((LPCTSTR)FileName, (LPCTSTR)buffer,0);
```

А именно: в переменной FileName содержится, не знаю что, но явно не путь... Как получить путь в эту переменную?

Comment: - Что такое `Path::GetDirectoryName` ? Это [функция из `C++ / CLI`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname#Y0) или что-то ваше?

- Если это `C++ / CLI,` то используйте [System::IO::File::Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/9706cfs5#Y0) для копирования файлов.

Comment: Я работаю с Win Form aplication. Диалог так использую:
 
 Stream^ myStream;
 if ( Form1::openFileDialog1->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK )
 {
  if ((myStream = openFileDialog1->OpenFile()) != nullptr)
  {
  }
 }

Как в MSDN. Path::GetDirectoryName - это не моё. Это я нашел в сети.
Можете пример кода привести?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FileDialog::FileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filename.aspx#Y200)

> Возвращает или задает строку, содержащую имя файла, выбранное в диалоговом окне файла.

Пример:

```
  OpenFileDialog^ ofd = gcnew OpenFileDialog;

  if (ofd->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK)
  {
     if ((ofd->OpenFile()) != nullptr)
     {
          filename = openFileDialog1->FileName;
     }
  }
```

filename - это строка `String^`.

Answer (score -2):

Сначала необходимо вызвать сам диалог. Не помню как конкретно в WinAPI, но в C# (диалоговые окна там из WinAPI) сначала необходимо вызвать Show() он возвращает булевское значение, в зависимости от того как завершился вызов диалога, если возвращает true, то путь лежит в поле FileName, иначе Вы нажали произошла какая-либо ошибка или кнопка отмена была нажата.

---

И вообще, для таких вопросов есть msdn. и Google